# returning an object returns undefined on second iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, object, ads

I have a couple scripts on a web page and I'm iterating through them, figuring out which are ad calls (contain a specific string), and then parsing those script tags to grab some url parameters from those script tags.

```
var cmunt_uniqueId, cmnunt_kw;

var scripts = jQuery('script');
var adObject = {};

jQuery(scripts).each(function(v,u) {

    if ((jQuery(u).attr('src') !== undefined) && (jQuery(u).attr('src').indexOf('cmnUNTmob-20121130.js') > -1)) {

    console.log('script.src[' + v + ']="' + jQuery(u).attr('src') + '"');

        var adCall = jQuery(u).attr('src');

        // console.log(adCall);

        var pubtag = adCall;
        var newtag = pubtag.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/, '');
        var parts = newtag.split('&');
        var part1 = parts[0].split('=');
        var part2 = parts[1].split('=');
        var cmn_site_unit = part1[1].split('/');
        var cmn_site = cmn_site_unit[0];
        var cmn_unit = cmn_site_unit[1];
        cmnunt_kw = part2[1];
        var cmunt_uniqueId = getCookie('__utma');


    adObject['cmn_unit'] = cmn_unit;
    adObject['cmn_site'] = cmn_site;

    console.log('inside function');
    console.log(adObject['cmn_site']);
    console.log(adObject['cmn_unit']);

    return adObject;
    }
});


console.log('outside function');   
console.log(adObject['cmn_site']);
console.log(adObject['cmn_unit']);
```

Inside the function, on both executions the variables are set and assigned to an object for parsing outside of the function. Outside of the function, on the second execution the variables are returning as undefined.

Here is the page calling running the script:
[WebPage](http://complexmedianetwork.com/test/site/mobile/demo8b.html)

You can see the output in the console using Firebug. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You're overwriting the object key with a new value on each iteration. You need another key/property to store more values.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing all your results in the same adObject property. When you loop the latest one overwrites the others.

Instead of adObject['cmn_unit'], use for example adObject[v]:

```
adObject[v] = {
    cmn_unit:cmn_unit,
    cmn_site:cmn_site
};
```

Also, jQuery(scripts) should really be scripts (although it is not an error, just inefficient).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your following line:

```
jQuery(scripts).each(function(v,u) {
```

for this one:

```
scripts.each(function(v,u) {
```

As your `scripts` variable already contained a jquery object.